# jquery/css drop down menu and pushes the div below it down onhover

Tags: jquery, css

I tried using jquery slide effect for a drop down menu (ala this tutorial: http://www.tuttoaster.com/jquery-dropdown-menu-in-wordpress/4/ --it seems like a pretty common way to make jquery drop downs) but whenever I hover over the list item, the submenu pushes down the div below it (my main content).  How can I fix this? I'd like to avoid absolutely positioning the content div. Thanks!

Comment: To help you need to post some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

#### Use absolute positioning

Giving the element which you are sliding in an absolute position will remove it from the calculation the parent container performs when decide its height

Absolute vs relative positioning demo: http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/E8twW/1/

#### Give container a fixed height

By giving the parent container a fixed height it no longer calculates its height using the heights of its relatively positioned child elements.

Fixed height with absolute and relative demo: http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/YtGLp/1/

Comment: thanks! css is still kinda confusing for me :) I used a height for the container and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, since you didn't exactly provide any of the code I can't really see where the problem lies. But you can position elements using absolute coordinates relative to the parent. Hm, it's kind of hard to explain so I'll just provide some small code

CSS:

```
.parent {
   position: relative;
}

.menu {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
   <ul class="menu">
      <li>Menu Item</li>
   </ul>
</div
```

In this case UL will be positioned absolute but relative to its parent. So element will be located on bottom left corner of parent DIV. This is also the way CSS dropdown menus are implemented.